# Center label on ggplot R stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, percentage

this is pretty straightforward but seems to be complicated in other posts that I've read. Posts related to this question are fairly old, so wondering if there is now a more efficient way to go about this.

I have created a simple stacked bar chart using ggplot in R. But I can't figure out how to place the labels properly. This is what I have currently after playing around for awhile.

```
cplot$label = paste0(cplot$percentage*100, "%")
cplot
ggplot(cplot, aes(y=percentage, x=Diagnosis,fill=DrugCode)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",color="black") +
   geom_text(aes(label = label,y=percentage),size=3.5,position=position_stack(vjust=2))
```

No luck in adjusting either, how can I just have the labels placed where they should be?

Comment: Change your `geom_text()` option for position with this: `position_stack(vjust = .5)`

Comment: I've tried that too - made many adjustments to that value and no luck

Comment: It must be a solution for your issue, just add `cplot` to your post using `dput(cplot)`. Many people want to help you !

Comment: Have you tried `position = position_fill()` in `geom_text`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you this works for me! Is this working because I had used geom_bar(position = "fill") ?